# Colorbox popup not loading completely when opened for first time after pageload is complete

Tags: jquery, html, css, magento, colorbox

I have setup default Magento CE 1.9.3.0 with base theme [here](http://115.112.143.25/ECO/mag/magento193/) along with custom News section.

Now when I click on the "Read More" link, for first time when page is just loaded, of any news item of center news section, the popup (colorbox popup) opens with missing "next" button and "close" button.

I think it's due to height and width issue of popup, but can't figure out why this issue occurs.

When I close the popup and then open it the second time, it loads perfectly fine with all buttons.

Please check the source of page to get the idea of HTML,CSS & Javascript libraries loaded for this middle News section as I can't create a fiddle due to unknown reasons.

Below are the `colorbox` and `owl-carousel` scripts I am using.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
//<![CDATA[
var $cnjQ = jQuery.noConflict();
$cnjQ(document).ready(function() {
    var $cnOwl = $cnjQ("#center_news");
    $cnOwl.owlCarousel({
        autoPlay: 2500,
        slideSpeed: 1500,
        loop:false,
        autoWidth:true,
        pagination: false,
        navigation: true,
        <?php echo $putTS ?>
        items: 1,
        itemsDesktop: [1199,1],
        itemsDesktopSmall: [979,1],
        itemsTablet: [768,1],
        itemsMobile: [600,1]
    });
    $cnjQ('.news-owlgrid').children().find('a.cn-read-more').each(function() {
        $cnjQ(this).colorbox({
            inline: true,
            width: "50%",
            rel: "cn-read-more",
            onLoad: function() {    
                $cnOwl.trigger('autoplay.stop.owl');
            },
            onClosed: function() {
                $cnOwl.trigger('autoplay.play.owl',[2000]);
            }
        });
    });
});
//]]>
</script>
```

Anyone with any suggestions ?

Comment: I can't seem to find any buttons. What are they supposed to look like?

Comment: Next and Previous buttons/arrows, you can see 1 button is already loaded when popup opens for first time but not both next and prevuious, as there are slides before and after the current slide in popup.

Comment: I see the close button on the pop-up, but see neither the next nor previous buttons following subsequent re-openings of the pop-up.  Furthermore, I do not see HTML mark-up for the previous or next buttons, upon inspecting the pop-up.  Looks like they are missing completely...

Comment: @jacefarm I was trying other options, like Fancybox, now I have changed to Colorbox again, please clear your Browser history and check again, the same link.

Comment: @VickyDev What are your thoughts on the answer I've provided below...?

Comment: Please check again, it shows "next" button when popup opened for first time after page load, but not the "previous" button.

Comment: @jacefarm If it was the case as your answer mentions, then why would it even show 1 button out of next/previous ? Please refresh the same link again after clearing the browser history.

Comment: this is due to the div width of ids cboxContent and cboxLoadedContent just comment the withd of these two after page load and click on read more then check

Answer (score 3):

This is purely a CSS issue.  The `close`, `next`, and `previous` buttons are present in the HTML mark-up, but they are sitting outside of the `#cboxWrapper` element's bounds.  `#cboxWrapper` has `overflow: hidden` which is hiding anything outside of its visible area.

You'll need to expand your pop-up's visible boundaries by changing the CSS applied to `#cboxWrapper`, or, move the `close`, `next`, and `previous` buttons within boundaries of its visible area.

You could try setting a larger value for the `width` property in your `colorbox` call as well.

Comment: Ok, you probably have the point, but why does this css issue occurs only when page is loaded and popup is opened for first time, why not also later times ? If the popup is closed and opened second time then this issue doesn't occur at all. So I think there could be Colorbox glitch, but don't know where or how to fix it.

Comment: Also I have tried most of the event functions related to Colorbox load but in vain, this issue keeps occurring when popup is opened for first time.

Comment: @VickyDev From what I could see of the CSS that was in the stylesheet, there were multiple style properties influencing the position of those buttons.  Perhaps start / simplify there?  You should be able to over-ride the Colorbox styles, if your CSS selectors are more granular in specificity.

Comment: Can you check again ? I have removed the unecessary CSSes from the page, now only Magento default css, Owl carousel css and Colorbox css are loaded, which are necessary, also they are loaded from single css file rather than different files. Still the same issue occurs, also can you suggest in form of code (css/js), how to solve this ? Also still not clear, why this occurs only when popup is loaded for first time and then it solves by itself when popup is closed and re-opened ?

Comment: @VickyDev The width and height constraints on all parent elements, from #cboxWrapper drilling down to #cboxLoadedContent, are constraining the visible area.  Those should not be constrained out-of-the-box for Colorbox, so, the width setting of 50% is suspect...

Comment: Well if I remove the width setting or set it to auto, it doesn't show popup area at all in entire page and whole page is overlayed. Also if I remove "inline: true" then it shows popup as white full with no content and buttons.

Comment: Even if I remove the Owl carousel from the picture the same issue occurs, so I think the script conflict between Owl and Colorbox is also ruled out.

Comment: Already tried setting the width to 75% and more, but still issue is there, cause I think width sets the innerwidth and not the outer width property. Could you suggest anything else in colorbox ?

Answer (score 2):

It looks like your divs have fixed heights. Is it possible that some of the class-names were overridden by magento-styles?

Another idea is to try to extract the Javascript and DOM-Code and execute it individually. If it don't work then, it's a problem with the code.

Looks like this is exactly your problem:
[Colorbox doesn't open at proper height when first opened](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3224264/colorbox-doesnt-open-at-proper-height-when-first-opened?rq=1)
This also looks related:
[jquery colorbox looks wrong the first time opened and then fine after that](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3286808/jquery-colorbox-looks-wrong-the-first-time-opened-and-then-fine-after-that?rq=1)